# "put() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)" when calling Paramiko sftp.put

Tags: python, sftp, scp, paramiko

I want to copy a text file from my local machine onto a remote server using SCP/SFTP. I already have an established an SSH channel between the source and destination.

```
sftp.put('sourcepath, destinationpath')
```

Above command gives an error:

> TypeError: put() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Answer (score 1):

That's rather a question on Python than Paramiko.

You have the syntax for passing the arguments wrong.

The `put` method is defined as

```
def put(self, localpath, remotepath, callback=None, confirm=True):
```

A call should be like:

```
sftp.put('sourcepath', 'destinationpath')
```

---

With your syntax, you are passing one string argument (to `localpath`) with a comma inside the string *value*.

The Python error message is bit confusing, because it counts even the implicit `self` argument. So you have provided a value to 2 parameters, `self` (implicitly by `sftp.`) and `localpath` (explicitly by `'sourcepath, destinationpath'`). You are missing the 3rd mandatory parameter, the `remotepath`. The other parameters are optional.